# Uid null when calling getProfile method

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When initializing my application, I call the `getProfile ()` method to return the user profile information and display on the screen.

But whenever it is initialized, the following error occurs:

```
ERROR TypeError: Can not read property 'uid' of null
```

**auth.service.ts:**

```
  authState: any = null;

  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
     this.authState = auth;
  });

  getProfile() {
    // error occurs when you try to access this.authState.uid but subscribe 
    // has not yet completed

    return this.afs.collection(`${this.authState.uid}`).doc('perfil-usuario')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(p => {
        return { ...p.payload.data() };
      });
  }
```

Is there a way to type authState for whenever I access a value such as displayName, photoURL or UID for no error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `switchMap` so you can wait for it.

```
 getProfile() {
    return this.afAuth.authState
        .switchMap(({uid}) =>
            this.afs
                .collection(`${uid}`)
                .doc('perfil-usuario')
                .snapshotChanges()
                .map(p => ({...p.payload.data()}))
         )
  }
```

Comment: How do I use it? I am running the way you described above but it is displaying error: `ERROR TypeError: this.afAuth.authState.flatMapLatest is not a function`

Comment: Oups, it has been renamed, could you try `switchMap` instead? If it still does not work add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'` on the top of your file